# Can not implement a save instance state for my switches

Tags: android

EDIT:

Okay, so I updated this to do what user "android developer" was suggesting, and the switches still remain unchecked every time I enter the app.

Here is a snippet of the code.. btw this is my first app so go easy. I'm learning.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("sw1",false);
}

public void onClick(View v) {}

public void sw1(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((Switch) view).isChecked();
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.sw1:
            if (checked) try {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "SW1 Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su","-c","mod1" });
                PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("sw1",true).commit();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            else try {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "SW1 NOT Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su","-c","mod1b" });
                PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("sw1",false).commit();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I am experienced in shell scripts, I know what I'm doing when I pass commands to the shell. But, making an app to imlement my shell scripts is the goal here. This is my first app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define "back out" of your app.

if you cause the acitivity to be destoryed by finishing it, it shouldn't restore the state and you should store it in real storage (sharePreferences, DB, internal/external storage,...).

however, if you wish to restore it after the configuration has changed (for example after rotating the device) , it should be restored for you automatically if you use android's normal views, and if you wish to restore totally new customized views, restore them on the onCreate() method and not on the onRestoreInstanceState() method.

another alternative is not to finish the activity, and show everything as if it does close, by using fragments instead of multiple activities.

Comment: Use the back button to close it is what I mean. And, I want the toggle switches to stay on if the user decides to turn it on. Even after a reboot. Edit: My app is portrait mode only.

Comment: please consider not having your app only in portrait mode (think of tablets too). anyway, in case you wish to restore their state even after a reboot, you must choose any of the methods i've written about to really store their values. for simplicity, you could store each view's id and its value upon each change , and restore them upon onCreate().

Comment: I will not be putting this on the market. It's for 1 phone specifically, so I'm not worried about the portrait mode being an issue. Since I have never done this before ever.. And after reading the tutorials and explanations, it all makes sense.. But when I try to make it work, I am lost.

Comment: saving: PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("test",true).commit(); restoring: PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("test",false);

Comment: also, even if you do target to a single device, you should think forward, since your app might get more successful and you might want to make it work on all other devices. there are even devices that work both as a smartphone and as a tablet, like the asus padfone.

Comment: when you target a singel device, you lose so many other potential devices. see this: http://opensignal.com/reports/fragmentation-2013/

Comment: Okay I will try to open up support for more devices. So should the saving line be directly after the onclick listener sees that it's checked? And should the restore be after onCreate?

Comment: the restore should be on the onCreate. the saving depends when you wish to save. if you only wish to save the state when the user exits the activity, then you can put it there. do note that instead of having this whole logic , you can simply use the PreferenceActivity and/or PreferenceFragment, which manage everything for you, using just XML .

Comment: Alright, I can't get it to work but surely I am just leaving something out.

Comment: you can show some more code if you wish. maybe i could find out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I chose the shared preferences route, learned a lot. Thank you.

Comment: And it worked for you? if the screen is of preferences (settings), you could use the Preferences method, which is even easier (you can even use XML )

Comment: Yep it worked, all except for the first time running the app, it doesn't load the defaults. But I just created a "First time setup" button to set all the defaults. Edit: Also I enabled rotation and scrolling that way more devices can use it.

Comment: glad it helped, though i don't understand why it didn't work for you. the code i've shown should work from the beginning. maybe you didn't reset the data of the app?